# Генерация строки-пароля из короткой строки

Tags: c++, криптография

Есть программа, для надежной работы которой требуется (желательно) длинный (`sizeof(текст) == sizeof(пароль)`) пароль. Пользователь обычно создает пароль ~5-10 символов. Как можно из короткой строки сгенерировать длинную?
Что-то типа:

1. `abcdefghi` -> `abcdefghiabcdefghiabcdefghi`
2. `abcdefghi` -> `abcdefghibcdefghiacdefghiab`
3. `abcdefghi` -> `???`

Длинная строка должна быть как можно более random.

Comment: В принципе можно, но секьюрности это врядли добавит.

Comment: Вы хотите на введенный пользователем пароль говорить "нет, твой пароль не ..., а вовсе даже ...."? Или пользователь вводит то, что вводит, а вы имеете в виду соль https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C_%28%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F%29 ?

Comment: Да, я про соль говорю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Основа стойкой криптографии — простые числа. Допустим, у нас есть строка из 2 символов `a` и `b`. С точки зрения математики, это два числа с ASCII-кодами 97 и 98. То есть перед нами число `x = 97 + 256 * 98`.

Возьмём вместо таблицы ASCII таблицу простых чисел и вместо сложения перемножим их.

97-е и 98-е простые числа это 457 и 461 соответственно. Получаем произведение 210677.

255-е простое число — это 1559. Произведение 1559*1559 = 2430481 или 0x251611. Три байта позволяют применить алгоритм UUE-кодирования, чтобы получить ASCII-строку.

Закодируем наше число 210677. Получаем строку `V<T!`.

Здесь уместно обратить внимание, что для строки `ba` данный метод тоже даст в результате строку `V<T!`. То есть исходный пароль невозможно будет однозначно восстановить, даже зная соль-строку.

Comment: Основа стойкой криптографии это **очень больщие** простые числа (сотни бит).

Answer (score 1):

Вот и используйте random().

Например, вычисляете на основе пароля любой 32-разрядный хэш и используете его для srandom(). Далее берете нужное количество random() для генерации символов.

Comment: Если алгоритм известен - это ничуть не повышает криптостойкость. Тогда лучше брать в качестве seed'а текущее время.

Comment: @Harry, хоть ТС и не говорил об этом, но мне показалось очевидным, что из одного и того же пароля каждый раз (и независимо от хоста) должна получаться **одна и та же последовательность** (возможно он хочет "ксорить" ей текст, зашифровывая его). В Вашем же предложении это не пройдет (ну, или придется где-то хранить это время).

Comment: Я неверно его понял. Я решил, что он хочет вместо короткого пароля строить длинный для большей криптостойкости. Но если известен детерминистический алгоритм, то такая система ничуть не лучше исходного. Какой смысл строить пароль в 20 символов из одного, если эти 19 символов однозначно выводятся из этого одного?...

Comment: @Harry, наверное надо подразумевать, что пароль (и его длина) на самом деле неизвестны. А в построении просто длинного пароля из короткого я вообще не не вижу смысла. Кто и как им будет пользоваться? Кстати, длинные сложные и часто изменяемые пароли сами по себе могут быть опасней простых. Их же никто не запоминает, все они где-то записаны и поэтому доступны.

Answer (score 0):

если ваш вопрос из категории  "домашнее задание", можно не читать ответ.

если для практических применений:

почитайте побольше про

- пароли
- соление и перчение паролей
- хэш-функции
- сложность вычисления
- почему вы не должны делать свою собственную криптографию.

самой удобной (для меня) библиотекой генерации токенов/шифрования - для С++  оказался [Botan](http://botan.randombit.net), можно использовать openssl  и т.д.